# Bash Script gives error in a loop passing thru multiple Mysqldump

Tags: backup, mysqldump

### The script

I'm experiencing an issue with this bash script:

```
dump_all_dbs(){
    $DOMAIN="mysql.domain.com"
    $DBS_FOLDER_BK="$HOME/_backup/"
    $DATA=("'1' 'dbname' 'dbuser' 'dbpassword' 'Yes'" "'2' 'dbname2' 'dbuser2' 'dbpassword2' 'Yes'")

    for i in "${DATA[@]}"; do 

            i=($i)

            # if 'Yes' do it if 'No' skip it 
            CHECK="${i[4]}"

            if [ $CHECK == "'Yes'" ];then

                # Extract the var from DATA
                ID=${i[0]} 
                DBNAME=${i[1]}
                DBUSR=${i[2]}
                DBPSW=${i[3]}

                # Clean from ' "
                ID="$(tr -d "\"\`'" <<<$ID)"
                DBNAME="$(tr -d "\"\`'" <<<$DBNAME)"
                DBUSR="$(tr -d "\"\`'" <<<$DBUSR)"

                # Go to the backup folder
                cd "$DB_FOLDER_BK"

                # Mysqldump
                mysqldump -v -P3306 -h"$DOMAIN" -u"$DBUSR" -p"$DBPSW" "$DBNAME" | gzip -c > "$DBNAME".gz
            else
                # Is 'No' just skip
                continue
            fi 
    done
}

dump_all_dbs_echoed(){
        mysqldump -v -P3306 -hmysql.domain.com -udbusername0 -p'password0' dbname0 | gzip -c > dbname0.gz
        mysqldump -v -P3306 -hmysql.domain.com -udbusername1 -p'password1' dbname1 | gzip -c > dbname1.gz
        mysqldump -v -P3306 -hmysql.domain.com -udbusername2 -p'password2' dbname2 | gzip -c > dbname2.gz
        mysqldump -v -P3306 -hmysql.domain.com -udbusername3 -p'password3' dbname3 | gzip -c > dbname3.gz
}
```

(NOTE: the password params in the original script was -p not -password,
echoed mysqldump with -password'password1'does not work)

Excluding the big security issue in storing in plain text password and usernames.

### The question

I would like to ask why if I'm running the script I receive this error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'myDSLconnection.domain.com' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

but if I run the single the mysqldump one by one via terminal or  "dumps_all_dbs_echoed" everything works perfectly (I did it echoing the params of the mysqldump and copy paste them)

anyone have an idea?

### Security Issue

how people treat the issue of store password or hashes?
I've tried pgp the file, but it seems not the right way for a chron process.

Comment: echo out the command it's executing, just to make sure it's ok. Does the password have any characters in that need escaping?

Comment: Hi Phil! I've already echoed the commands and copy pasted it. they works well. The password variable is stored into the DATA array between  two ' (like this 'password') and used as it is in between the params of mysqldump.

Comment: This might be just a simple permission issue. Try assigning the `dbuser` more rights by executing the following: `grant all on *.* to 'dbuser'@'%';`. Verify the dbuser's permissions by executing the following: `select user, host from mysql.user;` to verify the user can connect via your $DOMAIN variable.

Comment: So, you're saying that `$DBPSF` value is `'whatever'`, not just `whatever`? Note that `-password"'whatever'"` is not the same as `-password'whatever'`

Comment: @hot2use tnx for your suggestion. Actually, I can connect from my domain pretty well if I'm running the mysqldumps straight from the shell with all same params collected from $DATA they work fine. The issue appears to be just with the script. It's just 10days I'm playing with bash... I don't know most of it.

Comment: @mustaccio tnx! mnmn... which is the difference between the two? In my case, the data stored is 'whatever' as you said. this means in the script now is doing -password"'whatever'". Echoing the MySql command with the params the results appears to be just -password'whatever'. do you think there something wrong with it?

Comment: @mustaccio writing the example script upstairs **dump_all_dbs()** I've made a mistake using the -password instead -p, I thought it was the same but actually with the  **dump_all_dbs_echoed()** that contains the echoed  mysqldump with -password I got the usual error with the -p works well.